# Is there a way to replicate a function for different sample sizes in R?

Tags: r, simulation

I want to simulate this function for different sample sizes. To clarify, I don't want the number of times the simulation is being run to change (n), but rather I want to replicate this simulation for different sizes in the ok function (the current size in the ok function is 2 and I want to replicate this function for sizes 2 through 10).

Thank you so much. Please let me know if any part of this needs to be clarified.

```
simulate_f <- function(n){

  n <- 2000
  n.run <- 0
  
  for (i in 1:n){
  
 ok <- sample(1:4, size=2 ,replace=TRUE)

 if(var(ok)==0){
   n.run <- n.run + 1
   
 }
 
}

n.run/n

}

simulate_f()
```

Comment: Yes, I don't want n to change, but I want to replicate this function for different `size` in the `seas` variable. So I want this function to run for `size=2`, 'size=3` and so on until `size=10` and give me the results for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `n` is constant, we may not need that as argument.  Instead, use `size` as the input to be used as the variable component in the function

```
simulate_f <- function(size){

  n <- 1000
  n.run <- 0
  
  for (i in 1:n){
  
 ok <- sample(1:4, size=size ,replace=TRUE)

 if(var(ok)==0){
   n.run <- n.run + 1
   
 }
 
}

n.run/n

}

sapply(2:10, simulate_f)
```